# How to ensure mongoose.dropDatabase() can ONLY be called when connected to mongo-memory-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

We're using mongodb-memory-server for unit tests. After every unit test suite we execute:

```
await connection.dropDatabase();
await collection.deleteMany({});
```

To setup mongoose we have two different methods:

```
setupMongoose(); <--- Connects to our dev database in the cloud (Atlas)
setupMongooseWithMemoryServer(); <---- Connects mongoose to memory server.
```

We're a team of developers, and my worst fear is that someone uses "setupMongoose()" to setup unit tests by mistake some day. If that happens, dropDatabase() will be called for our "real" dev database. That would be a catastrophy.

**So how can I ensure that dropDatabase() and maybe collection.deleteMany({}) can NEVER ever be called on our cloud database?**

Some thoughts:
I have thought about setting up env variables and check for it before calling the dangerous methods. I've also already made a run time check:

```
checkForUnitTestEnv() {
    if (!this.init || process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID === undefined) {
        console.error('FATAL TRIED TO DROP DATABSE WITHOUT JEST!');
        throw 'FATAL TRIED TO DROP DATABSE WITHOUT JEST!';
    }
}
```

(this.init is only true if memory-server has been initialized).

But these methods are not fool proof. Errors can still happen if our developers are not careful. So I was hoping to either make it "illegal operations" with our database provider (Atlas) if possible, or check the mongoose connection uri on run time before calling the dangerous methods (but I haven't found a good way to do this yet).

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm in the same situation. Too easy to mess up...

Answer (score 0):

How about making `setupMongooseWithMemoryServer` drop the database, instead of each test?

```
export function setupMongooseWithMemoryServer() {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.FAKE_CONNECTION_STRING});
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  });
}
```